# Format Preserving Encryption FF1 Samples

Tags: encryption, format-preserving

NIST published methods for Format-Preserving Encryption and there is a link in the document giving [examples for FF1  methods](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/documents/Examples/FF1samples.pdf).

I am confused by the value of R given in [the examples](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/documents/Examples/FF1samples.pdf). $R$ is the output of PRF, and it should be 16 bytes. But all the $R$ values listed in the file are 32 bytes. Why is that?

---

For example, Page 1 , Round #0 , Step 6.ii:

```
R is [ 195, 184, 41, 161, 232, 100, 43, 120, 204, 41, 148, 123, 59, 147, 219, 99, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

The first 16 bytes is actually the output of PRF with the given arguments and I have implemented this, but the remaining 16 bytes (starting from 1, 2, ...) is actually the same as the value of $P$ given in Step 5:

```
P is [ 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 10, 10, 5, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0 ].
```

What is actually going on here?

Comment: Now I am confident that the `R` values listed in the [FF1 samples](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/documents/Examples/FF1samples.pdf) are actually wrong. Only the first 16 bytes should be listed there (which is actually the correct value). By the way, I also found another **typo** in **Sample #3**, where plaintext `<0123456789abcdefghi>`(Page 22) is encrypted and then decrypted to `<01234567809abcdefgh>` (Page 32).